# reCaptcha validation time out

Tags: c#, asp.net, recaptcha

I am trying to validate Google reCaptcha on my 1and1 hosted website. 
But when I execute this function on Server, It takes too long and my page is timed out.
Can anyone point me out what is causing problem.

```
private string VerifyRecaptcha(string secret, string responseCode)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
    request.Method = "POST";
    string postData = "secret=" + secret + "&response=" + responseCode;
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
     dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();
    return responseFromServer; 

}
```

Comment: Tip: user recaptcha dll in your solution....add dlls give a reference and then just use it to compare.

Comment: Its a website, and I am using just a single page aspx to process contact us form. so how can I ?

Comment: you need to add dll to get it wored as @Justcode stated

Comment: Is the dll available for reCaptcha version 2 ? In Google, they says only this post method.

Comment: @YesudassMoses, I am facing the same issue. Please let me know how this got resolved? The link you shared in the answer is going 404 error. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be due to firewall issues on the server being able to communicate to the google domain.  If you have a firewall, it may not be letting through calls to google, especially if it is filtering by IP address.  Google has a range of IP's that you need to open up.

Comment: I don't think 1and1 will block re-captcha. Is there any idea to unblock it if so ?

Comment: Hi steve. 
Thanks for your answer. It was blocked by 1and1. 
I used proxy as per this link, and fixed it. 
http://www.pagedowntech.com/faq/faq.aspx?faqid=144