# WebHost PHP CURL Request Fails With Error 7

Tags: php, curl

I am having trouble connecting to Google's site from my web host (1and1) when trying to verify a ReCaptcha response. I am using PHP and CURL to make the connection.

If I take the same code snippet and run locally it works fine and receives a response as expected.

I'm not too familiar with PHP and CURL so any help on what I should try/do will be greatly appreciated.

The code snippet is as follows:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$CaptchaSecretKey="MySecretKey";
$uCaptchaR="CaptchaResponse";

$curl = curl_init();

$captcha_verify_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$captcha_verify_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "secret=".$CaptchaSecretKey."&response=".$uCaptchaR);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$captcha_output = curl_exec ($curl);

var_dump($captcha_output);
echo nl2br("\n");
echo nl2br("\n");
var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl));
echo nl2br("\n");
echo nl2br("\n");
echo curl_errno($curl);
echo nl2br("\n");
echo nl2br("\n");
echo curl_error($curl);

curl_close ($curl);
?>
```

The output returned from the code is as follows:

```
    bool(false) 

array(26) { ["url"]=> string(47) "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify" ["content_type"]=> NULL ["http_code"]=> int(0) ["header_size"]=> int(0) ["request_size"]=> int(0) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(20.375) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(1.0E-6) ["connect_time"]=> float(0) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["size_upload"]=> float(0) ["size_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_upload"]=> float(0) ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" ["primary_ip"]=> string(0) "" ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } ["primary_port"]=> int(0) ["local_ip"]=> string(0) "" ["local_port"]=> int(0) } 

7

Failed to connect to www.google.com port 443: Timed out
```

Thanks.

Comment: "Failed to connect to www.google.com port 443: Timed out" -- seems clear enough: something's preventing you from connecting. This is not a problem with your script, but with your hosting company and (probably) their firewall settings. You should contact their support department.

Comment: I have tried and tried to no avail. I keep on getting through to someone who doesn't understand the issue. At one stage they were telling me that it's Googles problem and I should contact them first. Surely other people on 1and1's shared hosting platform must have experienced the same problem. I can;t be the only one trying to verify a reCaptcha response.

Comment: [here's a post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29117509/1941241) from 3 years ago that seems to indicate 1and1 does indeed block recaptcha. They solved it by using a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The issue has been resolved by adding the following line into the CURL script.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'http://ntproxyus.lxa.perfora.net:3128');
```

Hopefully this will help someone else too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to add the IP Address(get ip address @ https://www.site24x7.com/find-ip-address-of-web-site.html[get ip address or url](https://www.site24x7.com/find-ip-address-of-web-site.html)) of the URL you are making reference to in the CURL function to YOUR WEB SERVER OUTGOING CONNECTION (set as allowed connection) or as it may appear in your cpanel just enable it.

That will solve a lot of ERROR 7 problem as regard web server curl function.